# Importing Jquery in Angular via webpack

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, webpack

Essentially I would like to only load jquery later in my project to reduce bundle size by importing it via webpack using

```
  import(/*webpackChunkName: "jquery" */ "jquery").then(({default: $}) => {
```

However I am receiving a:

```
 error TS2459: Type 'JQueryStatic' has no property 'default' and no string index signature.
```

I belive this is due to Typescript, is there anyway to import the library later in the project that typescript allows?

I know I'm able to as gsap is loaded in this way with no problems.

Comment: You need `--esModuleInterop` or at minimum `--alllowSyntheticDefaultImports`

Comment: thanks will try this.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds silly, Im using node to start the project and not the cli. I dont think those flags will work as I am using webpack as well.

Comment: They correspond to properties of the `"compilerOptions"` object in your `tsconfig.json`, i.e `{"compilerOptions": {"esModuleInterop": true}}`

Comment: Ah ok, tried and still same error  unfortunately.

Comment: That's very odd because I _know_ that works. Make sure your tools are up to date

Comment: I appreciate the guidance this is all a new area for me,  I'll update my cli right now. Im currently on Angular 6 and webpack 4.

Comment: That should be sufficient. Make sure your typescript and loaders are up to date

Comment: Sir, If I  could kiss you I would.  I'll be sure to read up on those properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain of the import format you are expecting you can let TS know about it by adding a type assertion to your importing code:

```
 (import(/*webpackChunkName: "jquery" */ "jquery") as Promise<{default: any}>).then(({default: $}) => {...});
```

Of course if you know the value of the `default` property you may type it there instead of falling back to losing type information through the use of `any`.

Comment: Unfortunatley got hit with a 
error TS2352: Type 'Promise<JQueryStatic>' cannot be converted to type 'Promise<{ default: any; }